# what if take limit to negative infinity in the definition of e as a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

By definition $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e.$$

But what about a similar limit where $n$ tends to negative infinity, i.e, $$\lim_{n\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n?$$

Why does that equal to $e$ too? Could someone give a simple proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\pm \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{n\to \pm \infty}\exp (n\log(1+\frac 1 n))=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp(\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x})=\exp(1)=e $$

Where we make the substitution $x=\frac 1 n$. The limit with the logarithm exists, so we get the answer.

Comment: so both can be transformed into the same limit, which is then solvable with L'Hospitals rule

Answer (score 8):

The following argument is based solely on the standard limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=e$.

For $|x|<1$ Bernoulli's inequality guarantees $(1+x)^n\geq1+nx$. Therefore
$$1-{1\over n}\leq \left(1-{1\over n^2}\right)^n\leq1\qquad(n\geq2)\ ,$$
and it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-{1\over n^2}\right)^n=1$. From this we conclude that
$$\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n={\left(1-{1\over n^2}\right)^n\over \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n}\to{1\over e}\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}}=
 \frac{1}{e^{-1}}=e$$

Comment: I reached the form lim(n->inf,1/(1-1/n)^n). But why is lim(n->inf,(1-1/n)^n)=e^(-1)? that is not obvious

Comment: Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( 1+r/n\right )^n=e^r$ for any real $r$.

Comment: this answer is also good, but I had to pick one, sorry

Comment: No problem, fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \\
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \\
&= \left[\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]\cdot\left[\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right] && \text{(product law of limits)} \\
&= \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \\
&= e.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here I give a proof what Matt L. said:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n = e^r, ~~~~ r\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align}

In fact,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n/r}\right)^{n/r}\right]^r \\
&= \left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n/r}\right)^{n/r}\right]^r \\
&= \left[\lim_{m\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}\right]^r \\
&= e^r.
\end{align}